# React(v4) - Check to see if user visits any router

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I am trying to make my app redirect the users to a login page if it does not detect a `Meteor.userId()`, and to the home page if they do have one.  The problem I am struggling with right now is getting a simple `console.log` function to run when a user visits a route (regardless of the path).  How would I do this from a file the manages all the routes and components without having to insert a boilerplate code in each component.

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor"
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Tracker } from "meteor/tracker";

import Login from "../ui/authentication/Login";
import Signup from "../ui/authentication/Signup";
import Home from "../ui/Home";
import searchNotes from "../ui/searchNotes"
import Note from "../ui/Note";
import fullSize from "../ui/fullSize"
import userProfile from "../ui/userProfile";
import AddNote from "../ui/AddNote";
import questions from "../ui/questions"
import NotFound from "../ui/NotFound";

export default class Routes extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("rendering page")
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Login path="/login" />
            <Signup path="/signup" />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
            <Route path={`/searchNotes/:subject`} component={Note} />
            <Route path={`/searchNotes`} component={searchNotes} />
            <Route path={`/fullSize/:noteId`} component={fullSize}/>
            <AddNote path="/addNote"/>
            <Route path="/questions" component={questions} />
            <Route component={userProfile} path={`/users/:userId`} />
            <NotFound />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, I tried doing `export default withRouter(Routes)` so I can change the redirect people to new pages, but when I do this it returns an error in the browser saying, `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined"`  If you know how to fix that, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you try with `history.listen` ? maybe is that what are you looking for
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#listening

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, kind of want to stick with the packages I have already.

Comment: And have you seen this example of the official documentation?
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: if you just want to console, adding console.log to your node modules might save you??

Comment: @ReiDien I am just doing a console.log to check if it's working I eventually want to add authentication to check if users are authenticated

Comment: use context then. router is available as context and you can get the history there

Comment: Context is unstable according to the react docs is there anything else?